# System.ObjectDisposedException when trying to list an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Trying to fix this error

```
public ActionResult MyEvents()
{
    Personne personne = (Personne)Session["User"];
        personne.Evenements.ToList();
        return View(personne);

}
```

Got the System.ObjectDisposedException and Evenements is null

Using many to many relation between Personne and Evenement so cannot read the join table in the db.

Comment: Please include all relevant parts of your code to your question as well as stack trace so it'd become easier to find the cause of your problem.

Comment: I am guessing that it's the database context that has been disposed and you are using lazy loading? But it's impossible to tell without the full error.

Comment: Ummm, you are storing an entity in the session and then you are retrieving it in controller method from the session? Please do not do that, store the id of the user in the session and maybe wrap the session getters/setters also to some other class instead of accessing session directly. Then get the "personne" from context and eager load the "evenements" by including them. You can cache stuff in the session but you should not be storing entities in there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Evenements` are probably being loaded using lazy loading (i.e. not retrieved until the property is accessed).

When you are coding web applications the connection used to fetch information is usually closed when the HTTP request ends.

Thus when you on the second request try to access `Evenements` property the connection have been closed. And you therefore get the `ObjectDisposedException`.

You can activate eager loading by using the `Include` method: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/eager-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx

That way the property have been loaded and stored for all future requests.